# Is there a way to escape accents on mongodb fulltext search

Tags: mongodb, lucene, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

With the new Atlas Search feature is there a way to escape accents.

I did this index :

```
{
 "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
 "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.standard",
 "mappings": {
   "dynamic": false,
   "fields": {
     "_id": {
       "type": "string",
       "analyzer": "lucene.keyword"
     },
     "firstName": {
       "type": "string",
       "analyzer": "lucene.french"
     },
     "lastName": {
       "type": "string",
       "analyzer": "lucene.french"
     },
     "email": {
       "type": "string",
       "analyzer": "lucene.standard"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

With this data :

```
db.testJTAFulltextSearch.insert({_id: "testFTS3", firstName: "René", lastName: "Martin", email: "rmartin@gmail.com"})
db.testJTAFulltextSearch.insert({_id: "testFTS4", firstName: "Rene", lastName: "Martin", email: "rmartin@gmail.com"})
```

And with this search :

```
db.testJTAFulltextSearch.aggregate([{$searchBeta: {index: "customer", text: {query: "René", path: ["_id", "firstName", "email"]}}}])
```

I got :

```
{ "_id" : "testFTS3", "firstName" : "René", "lastName" : "Martin", "email" : "rmartin@gmail.com" }
```

The accents are not escaped (é is supposed to be handled like a e).
I was expecting :

```
{ "_id" : "testFTS3", "firstName" : "René", "lastName" : "Martin", "email" : "rmartin@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : "testFTS4", "firstName" : "Rene", "lastName" : "Martin", "email" : "rmartin@gmail.com" }
```

**Is there a way to escape accents (diacritics) with Mongodb Atlas Search ?**

I guess that I need an ascii folding analyzer but I did not find it in the list of the analyzers : 
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/#analyzers-ref

Usage of collation does not seems to work :

```
db.testJTAFulltextSearch.aggregate([{$searchBeta: {index: "customer", text: {query: "René", path: ["_id", "firstName",
 "email"]}}}], {collation: {locale: "en", strength: 1}})
```

Still returns only "René"

Comment: did you try a [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation)?

Comment: @Joe no, I will give it a try. Sounds like a plan

Comment: @Joe : Collate is not taken into account in mongo FTS :/. I will update the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [`fuzzy`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/text/#text-ref) config? It doesn't seem to be enabled by default, but `fuzzy: { maxEdits: 2 }` should have you covered.

I had a [similar issue](https://twitter.com/_arthurdenner/status/1243563879592009735) recently but found out that was actually my fault for setting the wrong config (`prefixLength: 1` instead of the default value `0`) there - see the thread. In my case, I'm using the `term` operator instead of `text`, but I'm not sure how relevant that is.

Comment: Thx for your answer, yes fuzzy works, but I want to be diacritics incentive and have fuzzy enabled (Desire should match Désiré but not Dosiro)

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I don't think only diacritic is available at the moment or if they have any plans to add it.